# Using Task within ASMX Web Service

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0, asmx, pdfsharp

I have a web service (asmx) upgraded from 2.0 to 4.0. To improve performance we identified doing the tasks in parallel will be help. Below is structure of the code. Files are PDF files parsed and processed.

From the service a utility class object is instantiated an few parameters passed.

MyAppWebService.asmx -> `PrepareFiles(List<Obj0> param0, Obj1[] param1, string param2, int param3)`

Within `PrepareFiles()` I instantiate a helper class that takes `param2` and `param3`, say `hcObj.CreateFiles(string param2, int param3)`

`CreateFiles` based on `param2` and `param3` picks the source file and makes copies.

```
for(int i=0; i<param3; i++)
{
   // using File.copy I make copies of the files for parallel tasks to read them
}
int tasksInParallel = 4;
for(int i=0; i<param3; i++)
{
    for(int tt=0; tt<tasksInParallel; tt++;)
    {
       // the processing logic is encapsulated in another class so its being invoked as follows
       // construct file name to pass to method
       Task<int> task = Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(() => { return Service Package.processFile(newFilePath, fileId); });
     tskList.Add(task);
   }
   Task.WaitAll(tskList.ToArray());
}
```

This works fine when there is only on request to the web service. When we start sending multiple requests to the service it fails.

The machine has 8 cores. Have ensured the values passed to the thread are local to the for loop.

[image: JIT Debugger that appears]

Comment: Do you get an exception when the service fails? Nobody will be able to replicate the issue with the code snippet and the information you provide here. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks.. The issue is not with PDFSplit, the threads come up process the PDF as expected. No Exception from the threading part in the logs. I wanted to verify if I have put in the code structure the right way. If i look into the process in the windows machine, a **Microsoft Visual Studio JIT Debugger** process appears when there are 2 parallel requests sent and the service becomes unavailable. In a while i can add screenshot of the Task Manager.